# There is a username called Microsoft on my login screen

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

Today when I logged in to my computer, I noticed a new user called 'Microsoft', I thought it was useless and deleted it. What was that user? Is it important? I also didn't install any applications.

Comment: You delete it then ask if it is important?, you need to break that bad habit. Its an online account with Microsoft, if you don't use it no worries.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Yes, it's true I need to stop doing that.